# A particular nonlinear second-order ODE with parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the ODE:
$$ y'' = \frac{ay(y')^2}{1+ay^2}$$
where $a \geq 0$ is a given parameter, and suppose we have initial conditions $y(0) = \mu, y'(0) = \eta$. WolframAlpha tells me that when $a = 1$ we have a general solution of the form $y = \sinh(c_1(c_2+x))$. Of course if $a = 0$ we get a solution of the form $y = c_1 x + c_2$. Is there anything that can be said about the case of general $a$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $a>0$, let $z:=\sqrt{a}y$. Rewriting the ODE in terms of $z$, it becomes
$$
z''=\frac{z(z')^2}{1+z^2}, \tag{1}
$$
which is the original ODE in the case $a=1$. Therefore, you can use the solution provided by WolframAlpha in this case to write the solution for $a>0$ as
$$
y(x)=\frac{\sinh(c_1(c_2+x))}{\sqrt{a}}. \tag{2}
$$

Answer (score 3):

For $a>0$, $$y'' = \frac{ay(y')^2}{1+ay^2}\implies \frac{y''}{y'}=\frac{ayy'}{1+ay^2}\implies \ln (y'/\eta)=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+ay^2}{1+a\mu^2}\right) \implies \frac{y'}{\eta}=\sqrt{\frac{1+ay^2}{1+a\mu^2}}\implies y'=C\sqrt{1+ay^2}\implies \frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+ay^2}}=C\implies y(x)=\frac{\sinh (\sqrt{a}C_1+C\sqrt{a}x)}{\sqrt{a}},$$ where $$C=\frac{\eta}{\sqrt{1+a\mu^2}}.$$ Adjust $C_1$ to your initial values.

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment.*

This equation becomes very simple if we switch variables
$$-\frac{x''}{\left(x'\right)^3}=\frac {a y}{1+a y^2} \frac 1{\left(x'\right)^2}$$ that is to say
$$\frac{x''}{x'}=-\frac {a y}{1+a y^2}\quad \implies \log(x')+c_1=-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(1+a y^2\right)$$
$$x+c_1=c_2\frac{\sinh ^{-1}\left(y\sqrt{a} \right)}{\sqrt{a}}$$

Just inverse and apply conditions.